# Graphics Cards that have SDI outs

Tags: conversion, hardware, sdi

I am looking for a medium to high end graphics card that has SDI outputs. I have a home studio with a SDI matrix switch and I want to hook my Gaming Computer into this rig. I am planning on doing some gaming livestreams, and I want to use my studio m/e switch to control the stream.

My other idea was to use some DVI to SDI converter, but since I have multiple monitors, it would probably be cheaper to replace my graphics cards

Comment: Honestly, a GeForce + Converter is going to be cheaper than a Quadro + SDI Option board, probably by a factor of several thousand dollars.  Easiest is probably to set up a mirrored output for your monitor and the SDI converter, and you can play and route the SDI separately.

Comment: Yeah I found the quadro +sdi but was unclear if I could game with it. It seemed more targeted towards developers. I think I will just buy a high quality scan converter then and use my existing graphics card. I am thinking of the blackmagic teras 2d converter, but we shall see what my budget holds

Comment: @sww1235 - I had a Quadro in my first laptop in college.  It was great for running Maya and Softimage, but it could barely run even old games.  Quadro's are designed for OpenGL and array processing support.  They are not designed to efficiently implement DirectX stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are best off to convert from a supported format (DVI, HDMI, maybe even DisplayPort) to SDI.  SDI cards are not designed for gaming, they are designed for workstations and video.  You aren't going to get a good quality gaming graphics card with SDI outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Most current graphics cards will have HDMI output and a HDMI to SDI convertor might be cheaper solution than a DVI to SDI.

Comment: Great point about HDMI possibly being cheaper.  I think the costs are roughly similar on the Black Magic Design ones, but it is worth highlighting that it doesn't have to be DVI.

Comment: Cheers AJ - noted that the costs can be similar.

Comment: Looks like HDMI is about $100 cheaper than DVI, so, worth using whatever the card already has. :)

Comment: Sounds good. I would probably use either DisplayPort or DVI as they lock. Interesting that HDMI is cheaper.